# how to display the current age (25 yrs 11 months 20 days)of a person in android?

Tags: android

i have written a program to calcuate the current age of a person like (24 yrs 10 months 20 days) , but somehow i m getting it wrong especially in the year , instead of showing two digit number it is showing four digit number and that too in minus , please need some help to correct my mistake

also attaching the images to show the output

[image]

[image]

Below is my code , there are two classes one is MainActivity and the other is AgeCalculation

Code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView tname, tname1, tdob, tage, tage1, tdobdisplay;
EditText editname;
Button bdate;
DatePickerDialog pickerDialog;
int startYear = 1970;
int startMonth = 1;
int startDay = 1;
private AgeCalculation age = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tname1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tdob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tdobdisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    bdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tage1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    age = new AgeCalculation();

    bdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            pickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            startDay = dayOfMonth;
                            startMonth = monthOfYear;
                            startYear = year;
                            age.setDateOfBirth(startYear, startMonth,
                                    startDay);
                            String user = editname.getText().toString();

                            tname1.setText("Hello " + user);

                            tdobdisplay.setText(startDay + "-"
                                    + (startMonth + 1) + "-" + startYear);
                            calculateAge();

                        }

                        private void calculateAge() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            age.calcualteYear();
                            age.calcualteMonth();
                            age.calcualteDay();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getBaseContext(),
                                    "click the resulted button"
                                            + age.getResult(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            tage1.setText(age.getResult());
                        }
                    }, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            pickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Code for AgeCalculation

```
public class AgeCalculation {

private int startYear;
private int startMonth;
private int startDay;
private int endYear;
private int endMonth;
private int endDay;
private int resYear;
private int resMonth;
private int resDay;
private Calendar start;
private Calendar end;

public String getCurrentDate() {
    end = Calendar.getInstance();
    endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    endMonth = end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    endMonth++;
    endDay = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return endDay + ":" + endMonth + ":" + endYear;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
    startYear = sYear;
    startMonth = sMonth;
    startMonth++;
    startDay = sDay;

}

public void calcualteYear() {
    resYear = endYear - startYear;

}

public void calcualteMonth() {
    if (endMonth >= startMonth) {
        resMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
    } else {
        resMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
        resMonth = 12 + resMonth;
        resYear--;
    }

}

public void calcualteDay() {

    if (endDay >= startDay) {
        resDay = endDay - startDay;
    } else {
        resDay = endDay - startDay;
        resDay = 30 + resDay;
        if (resMonth == 0) {
            resMonth = 11;
            resYear--;
        } else {
            resMonth--;
        }

    }
}

public String getResult() {

    return resYear + "-" + resMonth + "-" + resDay;
}

public long getSeconde() {
    start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
    start.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
    start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 30);
    long now = end.getTimeInMillis();
    long old = start.getTimeInMillis();
    long diff = old - now;
    return diff / 1000;
}
```

}

i have attached two images because of two different results 
in my calculateDay() ,if i change my if(resMonth == 0){ resMonth=11 } , i get the second image as output and if change it to if(resMonth==1){resMonth=12} i get the first image output , but in place of the year which i coming in four digits and in minus i want the current age of a person (like 24 , 25 , 30)
Any suggestions are welcomed 
Thanking You

Comment: Edit your question.You add picture two times.

Comment: yes sir , because i got 2 different outputs , so i needed to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to call `getCurrentDate()` in your `AgeCalculation`, which means `endYear`, `endMonth`, and `endDay` are never set, and instead initialized to zero - which explains your bad calculations.

To remedy this, simply add `age.getCurrentDate()` as the first line in your `calculateAge()` function. Right before you calculate year, month, and day.

Alternatively, since you never actually use that function, I would recommend pulling those 5-6 lines out of `getCurrentDate()` and putting them in a Constructor. For example:

```
public AgeCalculation() {
    end = Calendar.getInstance();
    endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    endMonth = end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    endMonth++;
    endDay = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

This way, whenever you create a new AgeCalculation object, the current date will already be set. No need to call a function to initialize everything. Then, you can just delete the `getCurrentDate()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working

```
    GregorianCalendar d1 = new GregorianCalendar(1992, 8 - 1, 17);
    GregorianCalendar d2 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 6 - 1, 18);

    d2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -d1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    d2.add(Calendar.MONTH, -d1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    d2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -d1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);

    int y = d2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int m = d2.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int d = d2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1;
```